# What is the apgcc schema in Amazon RDS Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aurora

Recently a mysterious new schema called `apgcc` appeared in every database in our testing Aurora Postgresql cluster (eu-west region). It is owned by the `rdsadmin` account. What is it, and where did it come from?

[image: Schema in pgadmin]

I am aware of a reference to `apgcc` in a [launch announcement for Tokyo region](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/amazon-aurora-with-postgresql-come-tokyo/). Twitter [reveals that this has happened to others](https://twitter.com/_a_d_r_1_a_n_/status/1062071589552971776).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the answer [from Kevin Jernigan of Amazon](https://twitter.com/kjerniga/status/1065328886957907969):

> A recent change in the Aurora PostgreSQL infrastructure made some internal schemas visible to customers. The “apgcc” schema is used for internal maintenance, and we are happy to drop it for you if it is causing an issue. We will address this in a future release.